# I have created react js exchange , and after sometime in chrome browser only showing AW,Snap error code SIGILL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native, exchange-server

here is the image of that page, we have huge amount of order coming through socket and this issue is only in chrome browser(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo1cV.png). i have checked on Firefox there is not issue there,how i can debugs the issue through my platform or through customising the code
I have tried to customise the order book and data that coming through socket, previously i have managed through redux but now i have change the flow its coming directly through useState in order book.
How i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.